# Applying own function on rows by dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am newbie in R, I was searching solution a lot, need your help :).

I am trying to apply code that will create new column with summarised values from the same table with some conditions.

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)
a<-data.frame(weeks=1:52, index=sample(1:3,52,replace=TRUE),factory=sample(c('A','B'),52, replace=TRUE),qnt=sample(1:10,52,replace = TRUE))
a

qnt_sum<-function(x,y,z){
  a %>% filter(index==x & factory==z) %>%
    filter(weeks > (y - 4) & weeks <= y)  %>%
    summarise(suma = sum(qnt)) 
}

a %>% 
  mutate(sum_qnt=lapply(index,qnt_sum,weeks,factory))

qnt_sum(2,5,'B')
```

but when applying in mutate I got only errors, with this particular code

> Error: Result must have length 16, not 52

but I was trying many variations with this code and I got a lot of different errors. I got a feeling that i have wrong approach to the problem.

expected values sample

[image]

Comment: What is your expected output? Is there any reason to use `lapply` instead of more `tidyverse` alternatives? Please also set seed.

Comment: Have a look at `purrr::pmap`.  I think the problem here is that you are passing the whole vectors `weeks` and `factory` to `qnt_sum`, rather than just the values corresponding to the single value of `index`.

Comment: added expected values table, NelsonGon - couldnt find one yet. Andrew Gustar - thx, i will try.

Comment: If you're going to show expected values, you're going to need to set the seed first using `set.seed()`.

Comment: Right, thank you i edited my post. moth answer  as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
a %>% mutate(sum_qnt=mapply(qnt_sum, index, weeks, factory))
```

Comment: thank you, looks like this solve my problem!! i thought i was trying all variations of apply, but probably i missed this one or didnt do that correct